# How much potash should I give garlic?

Tags: garlic, potash

I was reading up on garlic fertilizing, and was wondering how much potash to give my garlic plants. I don't know much about it, except the fact it is garlic from a single clove off a bulb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garlic’s demand for K ranges from 125 to 180 kg K2O/ha (Bertoni and Morard du L. Espagnacq, 1988; Zink, 1963).

If you're autumn planting where this is Oct-Nov, then the [RHS advises](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gardening/how-to-grow/how-to-grow-garlic-advice-from-the-rhs/)

> Apply a general fertiliser, such as Growmore, at planting time at 2oz per sq yd (50g per sq m) followed by a light dressing of 1oz sq yd (25g sq m) of sulphate of potash in February.

But if your soil has plenty of potassium, you should not need to add more.

Comment: The area I planted my first cloves is booming, because it was where we dumped all the ash one winter a few years ago, and nothing else was willing to grow there (i.e. 1/2 inch over a winter).

Comment: You're going to have to post a picture of your final bulbs!

Comment: I will do that with the question of "what type of garlic is this". It's already at least double the size of the cloves I planted, and incredibly firm.